# Should VSCode workspace be consistent between MacOS and Windows clients?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VSCode ssh plugin to work on remote server (Linux) from 2 clients: Windows and MacOS. After finishing on one machine I'd expect to continue on another opening same `.code-workspace` server file, but instead clean workspace loaded.
Is there a way to sync the workspace between Win and MacOS VSCodes?

Comment: what do you mean by "clean workspace loaded" what isn't clean that you are observing?

Comment: @starball at least keep open editors, plugins state